# How do I report a bug in Kentico 9?

Tags: kentico

I spotted a bug in Kentico 9, how can I discus it and report it to Kentico developers? I don't think that StackOverflow or any type of Q&A forum is a right place where report bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have a bug reporting page: http://www.kentico.com/services/submit-support-issue

Answer (score 3):

You can submit a bug via [Kentico`s submit support issue page](http://www.kentico.com/services/submit-support-issue) or directly to mail: support@kentico.com or within *Submit a support issue* app in Kentico CMS or EMS (see attached image bellow). Please note there is 24/7 phone support, too (phone numbers are mentioned on the page above).

[image]

**Please note**, it is a good idea to check if your issue was not already resolved in your version of Kentico CMS or EMC - you can check it on [Kentico devnet](http://devnet.kentico.com/download/hotfixes).